# Is it appropriate to ask for feedback about a website's code on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, questions

Is it OK to ask for feedback on Stack Overflow about websites we build, such as asking whether the code looks pretty valid and clean, or whether a certain effect should be done in a different way?

Answer (score 4):

Clean and Valid code should be decided upon by a Validator. Search Google for that one. If you are having a problem with your website, feel free to ask about it. Just provide excerpts of code instead of pointing us to your website.

Also, if it isn't a actual question, it shouldn't be on StackOverflow.

Comment: How about design questions - as in, does this site look professional? I guess it doesn't belong?

Comment: You can try, and if it gets closed you'll know for sure, but this is more of a 'programming' website instead of a 'design' website.

Comment: Design questions do not belong. Not programming related.

Answer (score 3):

No. [As Chacha102 notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12970/feedback-on-website/12971#12971), there are validators to validate your code. [As Umsd notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12970/feedback-on-website/12976#12976), soft, subjective questions are a bad fit for SO.

Questions that point to a website or huge chunk of code and ask something vague like "does it look ok" are bound to generate either irritation or indifference. As [the FAQ notes](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), questions should be:

> - detailed and specific
> - written clearly and simply
> - of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. For questions such as "Does this site look professional", you should probably get feedback from the intended users (customers) of your website, as their preference for a professional look might be vastly different from some random folks on Stack Overflow.

Comment: -1, OP was asking about code quality, not frontend stuff.